# No marketplace entries found to handle Execution

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to import a maven project to eclipse with M2eclipse plugin installed on. I get this 2 errors:

> "No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-compile, in /pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."

> "No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-testCompile, in /pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."

Can someone tell me what is the problem here?

This is my pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.tempus</groupId>
        <artifactId>inscription</artifactId>
        <name>Inscription</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <java-version>1.6</java-version>
            <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
            <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
            <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- AspectJ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- @Inject -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Hibernate -->
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
                <version>4.1.7.Final</version> </dependency> -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Entity Manager -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Commons pool -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- javax validation -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId> 
                <version>4.0.4.Final</version> </dependency> -->


            <!-- Ajouter -->
            <!-- DPCP -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>20030825.184428</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Fin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Mysql -->
            <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
                <version>5.1.15</version> </dependency> -->
            <!-- Transaction -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Oracle -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Ajouter -->
            <!-- Spring ORM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Bean -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- AOP -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- ASM -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Expression -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- TOMCAT -->
            <!-- Spring Security -->
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId> 
                  <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency> 
                <dependency> 
                  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
                  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
                   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version> 
                </dependency> 
            <!-- Fin spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Instrument -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Poi excell -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 2):

"The default maven plugin does not support Scala out of the box, so you need to install the m2eclipse-scala connector."
http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/